# Cordova : Cannot resolve module 'FileUploadOptions' and 'FileTransfer'

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am getting this error and unable to resolve the issue, here is the error I am getting. Please tell how to resolve this I am new for webpack

> ERROR in
>   .//babel-loader/lib!.//vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Teacher/Steps.vue
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'FileUploadOptions' in
>   E:\Projects\sbs-app\src\components\Teacher @
>   .//babel-loader/lib!.//vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Teacher/Steps.vue
>   15:25-53
>
> ERROR in
>   .//babel-loader/lib!.//vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Teacher/Steps.vue
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'FileTransfer' in
>   E:\Projects\sbs-app\src\components\Teacher @
>   .//babel-loader/lib!.//vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Teacher/Steps.vue
>   19:20-43

**Edit 1:**
Here are the steps when I am getting no errors

```
cordova create MyApp
cordova platform add browser
cordova platform add android
cordova run browser
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
-- other plugins --
```

using Vue in device ready function its working fine

but I have to create components, routers and resources in the project and also I have to minimize the size of APK file so using this [vue-cordova](https://github.com/kartsims/vue-cordova) to achive this everything is working until I use FileTransfer and FileUploadOptions as per cordova they are globally defined but webpack loader is unable to resolve module. Here is the [Webpack config](https://gist.github.com/webloper/d6a7ecd0ae92e7b0a64d75b24ab17ef5) this issue happens in both dev and production mode.

Comment: Be more specific in explaining your problem.What are the steps to reproduce this issue and what plugins have you used?

Comment: @Keerthi question updated

Comment: Here is the gist for [Teacher component](https://gist.github.com/webloper/742e5ed66534d9da2ecf95738ca7113c#file-steps-vue-L407)